# Is there an easy way to patch commands containing ^^J?

Tags: etoolbox, patching

I'm currently looking at various questions related to `multicol` and try giving answers to some of them. Often enough the answer would involve patching `\balance@columns` or similar macros and in that case `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox` fails because there are newline characters in the macro, e.g.,

```
       \message{^^JColumn
          \number\@tempcnta\space
           badness: \the\badness\space}%
```

Now, I can of course add the whole definition of `\balance@columns` to my answer, but this command has 165 lines, so I would rather like to avoid this.

Is there any easy way to patch nevertheless (or get rid of the `^^J` from the outside) that I'm missing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not sure why `^^J` is a problem, isn't it only special as `\newlinechar` when stuff is being used in `\write` ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\zz{aaa^^Jbbb \foo ccc}

\def\patchzz#1\foo#2\zzz{\def\zz{#1\bar#2}}

\show\zz
\expandafter\patchzz\zz\zzz

\show\zz



\stop
```

ah if `\patchcmd` uses `\scantokens` that is a write, so you probably just want to locally reset `\newlinechar`.

An example with `etoolbox` (From Joseph:-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\tracingpatches
\usepackage{multicol}
\makeatletter
\show\balance@columns
\edef\reset@newlinechar{\newlinechar\the\newlinechar}
\newlinechar-1 %
\patchcmd{\balance@columns}
  {\ifshr@nking \vfill \fi}
  {\CHANGED}
  {}
  {}
\show\balance@columns
\reset@newlinechar
```

Comment: Cool; I know it should have been easy, so that is how you gain reputation, stealing from @JosephWright :-)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `regexpatch`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\tracingxpatches
\usepackage{multicol}
\makeatletter
\show\balance@columns
\xpatchcmd{\balance@columns}
  {\ifshr@nking \vfill \fi}
  {\CHANGED}
  {}
  {}
\show\balance@columns
```